# How to get know if a process is waiting on stdin?

Tags: linux, bash, expect

Here is shell commands sequence with comments

```
#cd `mktemp -d`
mkfifo i
exec 3<>i                   # keep pipe open
bash <i &                   # run bash interpreter in background, use -x option to see what and when is executed 
echo 'echo X' >i            # writes X immediately
echo 'if echo -n A; then' >i   # waits for input till end of if-statement
echo 'echo B; fi' >i        # writes AB
echo 'echo C; sleep 7; echo D' >i   # does not wait on stdin while sleep
echo 'exit' >i              # also kill $(jobs -p)
```

#### Need to determine if the subprocess is waiting for input or if it is processing something.

May be `except` will help?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: Do you have `strace` on your system?

Comment: Unknown command strace

Comment: @psmears, i am looking for a way to execute a bash script highlighting every command before execution. Like --verbose.

Comment: Have you looked at "bash -x"?

Comment: @psmears, yes, `-x` expands variables. this is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is the same as within an interactive terminal. Just try:

```
you@yourpc ~ sleep 3<enter>
ls<enter>
wait...
you@yourpc ~ ls<inserted by bash>
file1 file2 file3 ...
```

The behaviour of a pipe in Linux is described under `man 7 pipe`

> **I/O on pipes and FIFOs**
>
> ...
>
> If a process attempts to read from an empty pipe, then read(2) will block until data is available.  If a  process  attempts
>          to  write  to  a full pipe (see below), then write(2) blocks until sufficient data has been read from the pipe to allow the write to complete.
>
> ...
>
> **Pipe capacity**
>
> A pipe has a limited capacity.  If the pipe is full, then a write(2) will block or fail, depending on  whether  the  O_NON‐
>          BLOCK flag is set (see below).  Different implementations have different limits for the pipe capacity.  Applications should
>          not rely on a particular capacity: an application should be designed so that a reading process consumes data as soon as  it
>          is available, so that a writing process does not remain blocked.

That means the writing end of a fifo has no information about when the reader has read or processed the input.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that pipe does provide no info about its status. I am looking for a workaround. Sure there is a way to determine if a process is blocked on a read() function.

Comment: No, there is no way. By design. That's what I wanted to point out.